# Is there any inconsistency in the C programming language?

Tags: c

Somewhere I read that a professor claimed that there is some inconsistency in the C programming langauge. Is this correct and if so, what is it?

I believe that I remember that the argument the professor put forward was that there was something you could do with one type (maybe char) but not with another (maybe int) and that for consistency it should be possible to do something that you actually can't with C.

Do you know what I mean here or is there no support for this notion?

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486059/inconsistency-in-programming-languages

Comment: Some inconsistencies are mentioned from the perspective of orthogonality [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality_(programming)).

Comment: This type of design question is likely to solicit debate and isn't a good fit for the *technical* Q&A format of StackOverflow. As such it's likely to be closed. However, it is **exactly** the right subject-matter for Programmers.StackExchange.com - you should ask it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char str[] = "Hello";
const char *str2 = "World";
```

If I understand you correctly, the above are 2 features that work meaningfully only for `char`

Comment: How is that an inconsistency?  Those statements are completely different.

Comment: @cdarke I dont mean between the two, I mean that each statement has no equivalent `int` form (without minor - major change)

Comment: The pointer case works fine with any pointer type. `const banana_t* str2 = "World";` should compile (but hopefully give warnings) and is fine unless it leads to a misaligned result; in that case it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Lundin is it fair to say then that the statement is only meaningfully useful in this form? My point of course that we cannot define an `int` array or a `banana_t` array in that form.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the `banana_t` case could be valid, in case it is a struct containing n number of characters and there are no alignment issues. But then of course, it would have been better to write `banana_t* b = { {'W','o'}, {'r','l'}, {'d','\0'} };`

Answer (score 3):

There are a few:

- unlike other types, you can't assign or pass arrays directly as entire objects
- `char x[]` declares either an array or a pointer, depending on where it occurs (in function parameters or not)
- `"str"` behaves either as an array (in `sizeof("str")` or `char s[] = "str"`) or as a pointer (in `puts("str");`)
- `"str"` is of type `char*`, but you can't legally modify what it points to much like if it's `const char*`
- you use `%f` for `double` in `printf()` but you use `%lf` for `double` and `%f` for `float` in `scanf()` and yet you use `f` for `float` constants (e.g. `1.0f`)
- `-1 > 1u`, not quite meaningful
- `UINT_MAX + 1 + 1.0` differs by a lot from `UINT_MAX + 1.0 + 1`, may be quite surprising as well
- etc

There are workarounds almost everywhere, though.

Answer (score 1):

It *may* be the fact that `char` can be signed or unsigned by default whereas `int` is always signed.

But, while that may be an inconsistency between types, it's not something I'd consider a fault - it's well understood (or it should be).

It may also be that sub-character types (ie, bitfields) are not addressable with the `&` address-of operator whereas other types like `char`, `int` and user-defined structures are. That's because multiple bitfields may be combined at a *single* address.

I don't doubt you could find fifty other minor inconsistencies in C, none of which would really be a reason to ditch the language.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't require full consistency. I just wanted more knowledge about C.

Answer (score 1):

```
"...is some inconsistency..."
```

No that is not correct, there are numerous inconsistencies, plural. To name all such issues would require an essay of many pages. To sum it up: the worst thing you can do is to assume that the C language is sane, consistent or logical.

Regarding the specific issue with char, there is a rule in C guaranteeing that all integer types are implicitly signed. For example, writing `int` is always completely equivalent to writing `signed int`. This is true for `int, long, short, long long`, but not for `char`.

This is because char is not only the smallest integer type, but it is also used to store characters, i.e. ASCII symbol values. Whether char is signed or unsigned by default is implementation-defined: a compiler may chose either form.

The reason for this is, if I remember correctly, some ancient backwards-compatibility issue where C compilers made before the first standardization of C had implemented char in different ways.

Another issue with char and other "small integer types" (short and bool) is that whenever they are part of an expression, they are implicitly type promoted in a way that is not consistent with how larger integer types are promoted. This is known as the *integer promotion rules* and are part of the "usual arithmetic conversions" ([more info here](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules)), another perfect example of where C is an inconsistent and illogical language.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's that `char` is not allowed padding bits while `int` is: the range of `unsigned char` values is always `2`<sup>`CHAR_BIT`</sup> wide, while that of `signed char` may be up to one less—a range for the `int` types can't be determined from its size and the value of `CHAR_BIT` (unless `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and `sizeof (int)` 2).